# Convert only first word of string to lower case

Tags: c

I have this function

```
char toLowerCase(char buf[]){
  for(int i =0; buf[i]; i++){
    buf[i] = tolower(buf[i]);
  }
 return *buf;
}
```

which gives the result

```
INPUT: HELoooO OOOOO
RESULT: heloooo ooooo
```

How do I modify this so that it only converts the first string to lower case ie. stop after " "?

I have attempted using strtok but it returns a segmentation fault after the first string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply exit the loop after the first space:

```
for (int i = 0; buf[i] && !isspace(buf[i]); ++i)
  buf[i] = tolower(buf[i]);
```

[`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) is defined in `ctype.h` just as `tolower`.

Some people will argue that using pointers will make the loop more readable but it's technically equivalent.

```
for (char * s = buf; *s && !isspace(*s); ++s)
  *s = tolower(*s);
```

If you want to skip over leading space, you'll need to modify the condition a little.

```
char * s = buf;
for (; *s && isspace(*s); ++s)
  continue;  /* skip leading space */
for (; *s && !isspace(*s); ++s)
  *s = tolower(*s);
```

Answer (score 4):

buf is a char array. You cannot check only for 0 (what you currently do), you also have to check for a whitespace. You can use the && operator to do this:

```
for(int i =0; buf[i] && buf[i] != ' '; i++){
```

Then the condition triggers if buf[i] is a \0 or buf[i] is a space.

Comment: oh I didn't realise you could do this.

Comment: Look at 5gon12eders answer. It is better than mine as it uses isspace. You can check for whatever you want in a loop. You even dont have to neccessarily have to check anything that has to do with the loop (even in most cases this would be sensless and/or bad practice).

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh ok just saw it definitely seems like the better method.

Comment: Thanks ;-) As long as your string does not contain space characters other than blanks (eg tabs) there is no difference except that `isspace` will probably be a little slower.  It's real advantage unfolds when locales come into play.  I prefer `isspace` because reading the code more directly tells me what it's meant to do.

Comment: You are definitivley right, i just didnt think about that right now. I would use it definitiveley in my code. I dont think its noteable slower, as long as you dont parse whole books...

Answer (score 0):

Just change the condition that keeps the for loop running:

```
void toLowerCase(char buf[]){
  for(int i =0; buf[i] && buf[i] != ' '; i++){
    buf[i] = tolower(buf[i]);
  }
}
```

I also removed the return value, since what you are returning is the first character of the string, which I don't think is what you intended (`*buf` is the same as `buf[0]`).